# How to hide/ remove Default back button when pushing view controller in react native?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I am developing application using react native. I have implemented NavigatorIOS component for navigations. It works fine with push and pop navigations but It shows default back button with previous page title and back arrow. I have designs like Cancel button on right side and no back / left button. I know it is just one line code in objective-c to hide back button.

I tried on react native documents but did not found anything regarding this.

could anyone have idea about it?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like there still ins't a way to hide the left/right buttons while pushing using NavigatorIOS.

A small hack that I use is setting the leftButtonTitle to a whitespace.

```
this.props.navigator.push({
  title: 'New Screen',
  leftButtonTitle: ' ',
  component: MyComponent,
  passProps: { id: 101 },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[According to the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator-comparison.html), support for NavigatorIOS is provided by the community, not Facebook and as such the features are limited. They recommend Navigator for "non-trivial apps". You're able to fully customize the nav bar in this component, but not for NaviagatorIOS.

> Includes a navigation bar by default; this navigation bar is not a React Native view component and the style can only be slightly modified.

You can always export that native view over the bridge, but that's probably more work than it's worth.